# How do I watch the event log for a specific entry in realtime, also getting the XML data?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, event-log

I'm building an application which should watch file for access, reading, writing, deleting.

I'm using the built in auditing system on a Windows 7 Pro. You turn it on in gpedit.msc, and then set the audit flags for the files you want to watch, and then you get entries in the security log.

What I want to do is watching the security log in real time, which I do like this:

```
static EventLog securityLog = new EventLog("Security", System.Environment.MachineName);

securityLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(OnEntryWritten);
securityLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

This works and calls my `OnEntryWritten`-Function.

```
public static void OnEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs entry)
```

`entry.Entry` is the `EntryWrittenEventArgs.Entry` Property, which doesn't seem to give me any access to the XML-properties of the entry, which I need, beecause it contains additional information.

What I'm trying to do afterwards is to query the event log via another `EventLogReader`, because I can get `entry.Entry.Index` which should be the `eventInstance.RecordId` of an event that I get from the `EventLogReader`.

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">">*[System[(EventRecordID=181616)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

works as XPath query directly in the event log, it gives back just one entry.

```
string query = "*[System[(EventRecordID=" + entry.Entry.Index + ")]]";

// Create Event Log Query and Reader
EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("Security",
                                              PathType.LogName,
                                              query);

EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);

// For each event returned from the query
for (EventRecord eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent(); eventInstance != null; eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent())
            {
                if (eventInstance.RecordId == entry.Entry.Index)  //RecordId and Index are the same thing: the identifier of the record/entry. 
                {
                    XDocument xml;
                    try
                    {
                        xml = XDocument.Parse(logReader.ReadEvent().ToXml());
                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //logger.Write(e.Message.ToString());
                        break;      //We seem to have a newline character in the logReader.ReadEvent() sometimes, but nothing else, so we can safely break here or completely ignore it.
                    }
```

This fails when I try to get the xml, why is that?

I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." which is an `System.NullReferenceException`. I'm not sure how this error actually can happen.

If I query the log like this

```
EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("Security",
                                              PathType.LogName,
                                              "*[EventData[Data[@Name='ObjectType'] and (Data='File')]] ");
```

it works without a problem.

What's the best way to do this, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The InstanceId does not return the same value as the index value.

Try the following snippet to get the correct ID

```
UInt16 eventid = (UInt16)(entry.Entry.InstanceId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the output of `XDocument.Parse(logReader.ReadEvent().ToXml())` ? Does `ToXml()` generate a proper XDocument (with header, root element...)? That might be the problem.

However if you don't stick to this solution, you could try to use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) or the official file monitoring tool from Microsoft: [Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I edited my question with some more detail. I don't get an xml in the first place, but a boring `System.NullReferenceException`, but it does work when I change my query.

I have to use the event log, FileSystemWatcher and others are out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call ReadEvent() you are retrieving the next event. Your query only returns one event. The line

```
xml = XDocument.Parse(logReader.ReadEvent().ToXml());
```

is the culprit.

Your code should look more like this:

```
string query = "*[System[(EventRecordID=" + entry.Entry.Index + ")]]";
// Create Event Log Query and Reader
EventLogQuery eventsQuery = new EventLogQuery("Security",
                                          PathType.LogName,
                                          query);
EventLogReader logReader = new EventLogReader(eventsQuery);

EventRecord eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent();
if (eventInstance != null)
{
    XDocument xml;
    try
    {
        xml = XDocument.Parse(eventInstance.ToXml());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //This probably won't happen now.
        break;      //We seem to have a newline character in the 
    }
}
```